# Migration to androidX not allowed in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, androidx

Facing the same issue as this post: [Migration to androidX missing in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51798511/migration-to-androidx-missing-in-android-studio)

In the Developer Documentation it says that you can migrate to AndroidX by doing the Following: Android Studio -> Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX But when i am following these steps, i end up at Refactor, because i only have got the option Migrate to AppCompat.

The difference is that my IDE is the current latest. Is there something else required to be done to make this option become available? I modified my gradle.properties to include:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

The above was stated in the official documentation here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

*See screenshots

[image: Migrate to AndroidX not allowed]

[image: Using AS 3.5]

Comment: Can you please share build.gradle ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same proble after you has updated AndroidStudio to 3.2 or later, you can modify your ".kts" to ".gradle". I solve my problem by this way.
Maybe your project contains something that "Migration to androidX" cannot support.